# Spring Boot Integration Tests override custom .properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am implementing integration tests and I have a problem with overriding custom properties that my application use.

Integration test sample:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = Application.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
  protected TestRestTemplate restClient;
```

The `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")` will override `application.properties` of my application with one that is provided

However, my application use custom property file like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:fileProvider/custom.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.sample.config")
public class SampleProviderConfigProperties {
```

In my application there is many external providers. Each of them like `SampleProviderConfigProperties` has with it's own configuration

In integration tests I would like to replace the provider `custom.properties` with configuration for test systems.

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: have you tried to add `@Profile("test")` or `@Profile("custom")`?

Comment: Where you mean to add it. @SampleProviderConfigProperties is then injected in other bean

Comment: `@TestPropertySource(locations= {"classpath:test.properties","classpath:testcustom.properties",....})` does this work for you?

Comment: @DirkDeyne It worked, I am amazed, I don't know how. My application.properties is mapped to test.properties, but others are mapped with the same name.